# SQL Server: how to achieve the tree nested level sort

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have tree structure based records(parent and child relationship) and I want to achieve nested level sort. Basically, I need level based sort as well as need to
maintain the parent and child relationship(sort child level). I have tried using CTE, but I could achieve only level based sort but problem is can't achieve
the parent and child relationship.

I tried below query

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE PARENTID IS NULL order by

CASE WHEN PARENTID IS NULL THEN 
    lower(name)
ELSE 
    (SELECT lower(name) FROM EMP WHERE ID=ROOTID) END  DESC,
ROOTID, JOBLEVEL, NAME
```

**Actual TABLE**

```
ID       PARENTID       NAME        FULLPATH   LEVEL  ROOTID
_____________________________________________________________               
1        NULL            AA             1        1      1
2        1               BB            1.2       2      1
3        1               ZZ            1.3       2      1
4        1               HH            1.4       2      1
5        2               RR            1.2.5     3      1
6        2               CC            1.2.6     3      1
7        3               DD            1.3.7     3      1
8        3               UU            1.3.8     3      1
9        4               GG            1.4.9     3      1
10       4               LL            1.4.10    3      1
11      NULL             KK            11        1      11
12      11               VV            11.12     2      11
```

**Actual Tree structure**

```
AA
    BB
    ZZ
    HH
        RR
        CC
        DD
        UU
        GG
        LL
KK
    VV
```

**Expected ASCENDING ORDER OF TABLE**

```
ID   PANTID     NAME    FULLPATH      LEVEL
____________________________________________            
1       NULL    AA          1           1

2       1       BB          1.2         2
6       2       CC          1.2.6       3
5       2       RR          1.2.5       3

4       1       HH          1.4         2
9       4       GG          1.9.4       3
10      4       LL          1.4.10      3

3       1       ZZ          1.3         2
7       3       DD          1.3.7       3
8       3       UU          1.3.8       3

11      NULL    KK          11          1
12      11      VV          11.12       2
```

**Expected ASCENDING TREE STRUCTURE**

```
AA  
    BB  
        CC
        RR
    HH
        GG
        LL
    ZZ
        DD
        UU
KK
        VV
```

**Expected DESCENDING  ORDER OF TABLE**

```
ID  PARENTID        NAME     FULLPATH     LEVEL
________________________________________________
11      NULL        KK          11          1
12      11          VV          11.12       2

1       NULL        AA          1           1

3       1           ZZ          1.3         2
7       3           DD          1.3.7       3
8       3           UU          1.3.8       3

4       1           HH          1.4         2
9       4           GG          1.9.4       3
10      4           LL          1.4.10      3

2       1           BB          1.2         2
6       2           CC          1.2.6       3
5       2           RR          1.2.5       3
```

**Expected DESCENDING TREE STRUCTURE**

```
KK
    VV
AA  
    ZZ
        UU
        DD
    BB  
        RR
        CC          
    HH
        LL
        GG
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! And make sure the result **makes sense** and looks reasonably useful to someone else looking at it and trying to make sense of it !

Comment: I see you dont like to accept answers,any reason for that?

Comment: apologize, how to accept the answer?

Comment: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: [How do I sort the results of a recursive query in an expanded tree-like fashion?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63153/how-do-i-sort-the-results-of-a-recursive-query-in-an-expanded-tree-like-fashion)

Comment: WITH RECURSIVE  is not working for me. I am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Is `FULLPATH` and actual field? You could use some clever string manipulation to convert it to a string that sorts exactly like you want (for example replacing all integers with a 6,7,8, however many you expect to need zero padded version). For example if you know you will never reach 1 million IDs turn 1 to 00000001, 1.2 to 0000001.0000002 etc. That should sort exactly as you want.

However this will sort same level IDs by ID and not by Name. If that is part of your specification which you do not mention but your example seems to do so, it will not work.

The only other ways I can think of have to do with assumption of a reasonable max level of nesting. In that case you would break each level into its own sub-query or view and re-integrate as linked tables.

Comment: Yes. I have populated the level and fullpath while inserting. Here, not only name but also other columns also available

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTE is the tool you should use. Here is working example for you. Note that your FULLPATH,   LEVEL, and  ROOTID fields are redundant.

```
declare @emp table (id int,parentId int, name varchar(10))--your table
insert @emp values                --test values
(1   ,     NULL    ,        'AA'), 
(2,        1,               'BB'),
(3,        1,               'ZZ'), 
(4,        1,               'HH'), 
(5,        2 ,              'RR'), 
(6,        2,               'CC'), 
(7,        3,               'DD'), 
(8,        3,               'UU'), 
(9,        4,               'GG'), 
(10,       4,               'LL'), 
(11,      NULL       ,      'KK'), 
(12,      11,               'VV') 

;with emps as (
--anckor query
select id, parentid, name, 
format(id,'00000') sort, --format is sql 2012+ feature
1 lvl, --calc levels
format(100000-id,'00000') descsort --trick for desc sort
from @emp where parentId is null
union all --must be ALL
--recursive query
select e.id, e.parentid, e.name, sort+format(e.id,'00000') sort,  lvl+1,descsort+format(e.id,'00000')
from @emp e 
inner join emps on e.parentId=emps.id
)
select * from emps
order by sort  --or **by descsort** if you want "desc"
```

### Edit for pre-2012 version

```
stuff('00000',5-len(cast(id as varchar)),1000,cast(id as varchar))
```

### update to sort by names as well

```
;with emps as (
select id, parentid, name, 
cast(left(name,2)+stuff('00000',5-len(cast(id as varchar)),1000,cast(id as varchar)) as varchar(max)) sort, --2008
--format(id,'00000') sort, 
1 lvl, 
format(100000-id,'00000') descsort -- use sort field as example
from @emp where parentId is null
union all
select e.id, e.parentid, e.name, 
sort+left(e.name,2)+stuff('00000',5-len(cast(e.id as varchar)),1000,cast(e.id as varchar)),
--sort+format(e.id,'00000') sort,  
lvl+1,descsort+format(e.id,'00000')
from @emp e 
inner join emps on e.parentId=emps.id
)
select * from emps
order by sort -- descsort
```

### This is for desc sort

```
;with emps as (
select id, parentid, name, 
cast(left(name,2)+stuff('00000',5-len(cast(id as varchar)),1000,cast(id as varchar)) as varchar(max)) sort, --2008
--format(id,'00000') sort, --2012
1 lvl, 
cast(stuff('00000',6-len(cast((100000-id) as varchar)),1000,cast((100000-id) as varchar))+left(name,2) as varchar(max)) descsort --2008
--format(100000-id,'00000') descsort -- use sort field as example
from @emp where parentId is null
union all
select e.id, e.parentid, e.name, 
sort+left(e.name,2)+stuff('00000',5-len(cast(e.id as varchar)),1000,cast(e.id as varchar)),
--sort+format(e.id,'00000') sort,  
lvl+1,
descsort+stuff('00000',6-len(cast(100000-e.id as varchar)),1000,cast(100000-e.id as varchar))+left(e.name,2)
--format(e.id,'00000')
from @emp e 
inner join emps on e.parentId=emps.id
)
select * from emps
order by --sort desc-- 
descsort
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2008. I can not use format(). I tried with +(concatenate). It is not helping me. I can not achieve the sort(nested level)

Comment: I tried with stuff, but name is not sorting. Also, we can not give guarantee the id is sequence e.g: parent id 30 and child id 20.

Comment: "we can not give guarantee the id is sequence". It doesn't matter. If id's are greater than 99999 then add 000s to the stuff mask.

Comment: I tried, asc query is working fine. But, descending is not working for name. I tried below one                                                                     cast(left(ISNULL(name,''),2) + stuff(cast(100000-id as varchar),5-len(cast(id as varchar)),1000,'00000') as varchar(max)) as descsort

Comment: Can you please give me descending order query also

Comment: Desc sorting is happen but nested level sorting is not working. I tried with 12L records for asc, it is taking 2 mins with the help of recursive CTE query. Is there any other way to resolve this nested level sort? As I said early, I have rootid, level and fullpath as readymade. Using those fields can we achieve ?